# If Dictionary/Array/Map Exists

Tags: asp.net, f#

so looking at a way in F# to check if a variable exists and if it does, if it's a dictionary.

The use case is a templating system, so there will be something like
{{dictionaryName|key}} in a HTML file.

And I only want to parse it if dictionaryName is a valid dictionary.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no way in F#  do use a variable that does not exist (you declare those and the compiler will check for you if the identifier was introduced/defined).

So I guess you want to check if it is `null` or - if not - an instance of `Dictionary`?

In this case you can use a [type test pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#type-test-pattern) match:

```ml
match value with
| null -> ... // what do you want the expressions value to be if null?
| :? Dictionary<string,string> as dict -> ... // you can use `dict` to compute your resulting-value
| _ -> ... // else/default - case
```

now this does assume you know the full type of your dictionary (I used `string` for the key and the value as an example)

If not you can either match against `IDictionary` of use reflection but I'd try this first.

---

#### Update

to pattern match on a dictionary-key/value:

```ml
match dict.TryGetValue key with
| (true, value) -> ...
| (false, _) -> ... // Key not in dictionary
```

Comment: Yup think that answers it. Will have to test but that definitely seems like what I’m wanting, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify, there are cases where the variable might not exist as the front end is completely decouple from the backend. So the HTML could contain a reference to a variable that simply doesn’t exist. So the dictionaries are actually stored in another dictionary of “allowedVariables”.

Comment: I guess I'd need more details on how you fetch/use those - the difference might be that you want to check the other dictionary first as some ways to query would throw an exception instead of returning `null` - but if you deal with dictionaries/objects that might be `null` this is a way you can approach this

Comment: Yeah I’m sure I can make both of your approaches work depending on how I approach it, so I appreciate the help. I think the dictionary in dictionary approach is probably the best way to go about it!